# Library not loaded error after brew install php56

Tags: macos, homebrew, php-5.6

I'm upgrading from php5.5 to php5.6 on OSX Mavericks using homebrew. I run

```
brew install php56
```

Everything runs and completes fine but when I run `php -v` the following error comes up

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.53.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, it was a symlink issue with the previous installation. Everything was fine after running

```
brew link --overwrite php56
```

**P.S.** Before running with `--overwrite`, try without. If you get the error below like I did, then go ahead.

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.3...
Error: Could not symlink bin/pear
Target /usr/local/bin/pear
is a symlink belonging to php55. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink php55

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite php56

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run php56
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
brew install node
```

Comment: This works for my problem. And I added a --force to remove all the history installs. `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force node icu4c
`

Comment: This was great. The problem in question surfaced for me after I installed Inkscape, so the php56-related solutions seemed a bit off-base for me. This runs quickly and was painless.

Comment: Has saved my day twice, now! This time it was due to brew-installing `ffmpeg` (after a `brew update`). Thanks for this minimal solution. Be careful to take a note of your existing version of Node before running this, in case you'd like to re-install the same version rather than the latest one.

Answer (score 7):

For me simply upgrading php helped.

```
brew upgrade php
```

The corresponding file `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.<version>.dylib` did not exist but a more recent one. So my php version was a bit behind compared to other dependents which probably upgraded icu4c when upgrading them. (Either node or postgresql?)

Answer (score 2):

previous solution was not working:

```
$ php -i
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.55.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

solved with:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade icu4c
```

see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1701

Answer (score 2):

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.53.dylib

It sounds like an issue with `icu4c`. So try:

```
brew uninstall icu4c && brew install icu4c
brew unlink icu4c && brew link icu4c --force
```

In case of further issues, investigate them by `brew doctor`.

Comment: Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/61.1

Answer (score 1):

For this to be fixed for me (Mavericks 10.9.5) necessitated the *entire* routine described [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1701), namely:

```
brew uninstall --force php56

brew update

brew tap --repair

find $(brew --cache) -mindepth 1 -print -delete

brew install -v php56
```

(and in my case I needed `brew install php56-mcrypt` as well, as that was missing.)

I'd had PHP 5.4 and 5.6 installed before, with 5.4 being the active (*"linked"*) one – I wanted to switch.  I'd installed the `php-switcher` package, which is a very neat way of letting you do this, but it wasn't working prior to the above procedure.

Comment: what abot --enable-opcache, you'll want that too

Comment: that 4th step deleted all files from my /Applications directory

Comment: @daleyjem I've replaced it with a safer version (see the GitHub page). The problem is, should you mistype `brew --cache` (which gives you the location of the download cache) it won't find the directory, but proceeds to do the rm anyway…

Answer (score 1):

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
brew install node
```

worked for me.