# Installing node with brew fails on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I'm trying to install node with homebrew on macOS Sierra. 
I run

```
 brew install node
```

After a seemingly successful install I get the following when trying to run `node`:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27896230) (replace `php56` with `node`) helps, but I use the official Node.js installer for Mac myself.

Comment: this worked for me: brew update && brew reinstall nodejs

Comment: Find the thread on github here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11713

Comment: @ScottFlack, *brew update; brew reinstall nodejs* may also work, since _reinstall nodejs_ can pass despite _brew update_ exiting non-zero (e.g., due to a misconfigured or unused tap).

Answer (score 126):

This is the series of incantations that eventually worked for me based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27896230) link suggested by @robertklep and @vovkasm.

```
brew uninstall --force node
brew uninstall icu4c && brew install icu4c
brew unlink icu4c && brew link icu4c --force
brew install node
```

I'm not sure if they're all needed, but given that I can't get my machine in the previous state... I'll just leave this info here, maybe it'll be useful for somebody else.

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked for me on Mac Os 10.13.4 High Sierra. I swear I'll never understand the need for --force. It's like "I really mean it, this time...".

Comment: I also had to uninstall node 8 for this to work. `brew uninstall node@8`. See https://medium.com/@mahcloud/mac-brew-node-10-upgrade-55d3e910eebb

Comment: Added --ignore-dependencies to uninstall commands and it worked great.

Comment: Just force uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me!

Comment: You may run into an error with NPM saying that it can't uninstall `icu4c` because it's a dependency for other applications. To get around this run: `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies icu4c && brew install icu4c`. This command replaces @mircealungu's 2nd command.

Answer (score 84):

In my case, `brew upgrade node` resolve the problem :)

Comment: I think you want `brew upgrade` instead, `update` gave me an error.

Answer (score 32):

Well I got this error trying to install `@angular/cli`, realized node might be out of date. Following @mircealungu 's exact steps didn't quite work for me, here is the modified version that worked for me.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force node
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force icu4c
brew install icu4c
brew unlink icu4c && brew link icu4c --force
brew install node
```

Comment: This did it for me. Also helped for my current project to just kill node_modules (`rm -rf node_modules`) and `npm install` all over again.

Comment: I got this problem after installing php56-pgsql via brew, this fixit for me.

Comment: Thanks, this answer saved my life. There are some stuff that I had to do outside of these steps.

Answer (score 26):

Upgrading node fixed a problem.

```
brew upgrade node
```

Answer (score 24):

I recently encountered a similar issue (after doing 
`brew switch node 9.8.0` to downgrade to a previous version of node)

```
dyld: Library not loaded: 
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.60.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

The issue is that node is picky about which version of icu4c it's looking for, and the version I had installed (62) was higher than node was expecting.

To fix, I made sure I had version 60 of icu4c selected.

First I found which versions I had with `brew info icu4c`, then did 
`brew switch icu4c 60.2` to select the one node was expecting.

Comment: how did you determine that node wanted version 60.2 -- thanks

Comment: @raison The version of icu4c that node is looking for is in the dyld error message. In this case, `60`. Compare that to the output of `brew info icu4c` to find a compatible version, e.g. `60.2`.

Comment: That's the best answer

Answer (score 17):

For me it was apparently a problem with the `icu4c` installation from brew.

```
brew reinstall icu4c
```

will reinstall `icu4c`.

if you don't have it installed,

```
brew install icu4c
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it saved me so much time and effort. Searching for this answer for very long time.

Comment: this should be accepted answer. this command saved me

Answer (score 15):

Seems file `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib` does not exists in you system.

Please ensure that `icu4c` installed with Homebrew.

1. `brew info icu4c`
2. If already installed, try reinstall: `brew reinstall icu4c`
3. If not installed, try install: `brew install icu4c`

Answer (score 15):

For high seirra,  just "brew upgrade" makes magic!

Comment: Same also for Mojave. Had the problem with the PHP installation and just typed your command. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

First I uninstall node and icu4c, force to uninstall all versions

```
brew uninstall --force --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
```

After install version 8 of Node

```
brew install node@8
```

If it already install, please just upgrade

```
brew upgrade node@8
```

And enter

```
node -v
```

v8.11.1

Comment: Thanks for the right command in right order! This has worked to remove icu4c and reinstall node version.

Answer (score 7):

This was triggered for me after a `brew upgrade` and `brew update` ran. I was able to fix it by simply re-installing the two items flagged as problems (which made sense to me):

```
brew reinstall node
brew reinstall icu4c
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me. I'm using High Sierra.

What fixed it for me was `brew upgrade`

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that works great over [here](http://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2018/08/macos-homebrew-installing-older-version-of-software.html). I'll briefly give the commands below.

First, cd into the homebrew formula directory:

```
cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
```

Git log:

```
git log --follow icu4c.rb
```

Choose the commit hash that matches the version you need. I needed version 61.1, thus chose the `6d9815` commit:

```
git checkout -b icu4c-61.1 6d9815
```

Reinstall:

```
brew reinstall ./icu4c.rb
```

Switch:

```
brew switch icu4c 61.1
```

That fixed it for me.

Credit: [hanxue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399759/hanxue)

Comment: also a great general fix for other library issues! had this issue with other libraries before, but this is by far the cleanest solution (with git branch, and just checking out old versions rather than manually editing the formula)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing worked for me but running this worked

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
brew uninstall --force node
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies icu4c
brew unlink icu4c && brew link icu4c --force
brew install node
```

Answer (score 1):

This error was given to me after migrating machines.

Even though everything was installed, when I went to check `node -v` or `npm version`, I'd get this error.

What fixed it was `brew reinstall icu4c`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my local php installation.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Solved the problem with this command. (check your version)

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"` from my `~/.bash_profile` file and it fixed my problem.

My error was:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

My `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib` contains `libicui18n.64.dylib`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by

```sh
cd /usr/local/Cellar
rm -rf node*/
rm -rf icu4c/
brew install node
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your icu4u Reference path is not set properly

first check you might instal icu4c or not by putting below comment in comment promt

`brew info icu4c`

or else reinstall

`brew reinstall icu4c`

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

hope This might help !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as a common software, just download installation package from official site:[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)

and then download a recommended version(currently 8.11.3, end with `.pkg`), install it as a common software, then u can use it. I tried so many methods, and only this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your machine. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

i run this on macos:

git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow

it takes around 20 minu