# My terminal can't check the version of node and npm can't use, and it prompts the following information

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, terminal

**I installed the latest version of the node using brew, but I got an error when I checked the version in the terminal.**

***The following is a description of the problem:***
dyld: initializer function 0x0 not in mapped image for /usr/local/bin/node  Abort trap: 6

Comment: check one of these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780207/installing-node-with-brew-fails-on-mac-os-sierra https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11713

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing node with brew fails on Mac OS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780207/installing-node-with-brew-fails-on-mac-os-sierra)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command in the terminal:

```
node -v
```

Check this url for details on installing or reinstalling node on a mac: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-install-nodejs-on-mac.cfm

Also check this link for more details to your issue and maybe update brew: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11713

```
brew upgrade node
```

Comment: It's tagged MacOS -- you don't run `apt` on macs

Comment: I see you are correct. Maybe this article will help you. You may need to re-install node. https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-install-nodejs-on-mac.cfm

Comment: I have included some more information to your issue maybe it will help.