# Error starting TypeScript language service in WebStorm 2018

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm new to using WebStorm (v2018.2 on Windows 7) and trying to work with TypeScript. And I am getting following error, despite trying many combinations of the TypeScript configuration settings in WebStorm.

> Error:Timeout on starting language service process

As a result, I'm unable to compile my .ts files within the IDE.

TypeScript is working fine from command line (i.e. successfully able to run `tsc` to compile .ts files).

I have thoroughly reviewed the WebStorm help documentation and other tutorials, but nowhere have I seen this error mentioned or how to resolve it.

Comment: Hve you contacted Jetbrains support? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us

Comment: what Typescript and Node.js versions are used? Please try enabling debug logging for `#com.intellij.lang.javascript.service.JSLanguageServiceQueue:trace` ( *Help | Debug log settings*), recreate the issue and provide the `idea.log.*` files (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) and `.log**` files created in your project root folder to support

Answer (score 18):

I've encountered this error a few times myself, and in my case it seems to be a problem with the node interpreter WebStorm is trying to use.

Earlier this week something I had installed via mac's `homebrew` package manager added a new/broken build of `node` to my system as a dependency.  When I started having issues with webstorm, I opened preferences > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript and saw that the Node interpreter was set to /usr/local/bin/node instead of my usual `nvm` path.  I opened a terminal and tried running the `node` executable it was pointed to, and found that it was throwing an error.

A lot of the specifics aren't really comparable to your situation since you're on Windows, but I think it's probably a similar root cause, a bad `node` executable is the only thing I've ever seen cause this error message.

Comment: Indeed, it was Node's fault! When I ran `which node`, a linking error was reported: `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node Reason: image not found`, indicating that Node was having problems. I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159489/5951226) to repair `node`: `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c && brew install node`, and the TypeScript service became healthy again after quitting and re-opening WebStorm. Thanks for saving me hours!

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem. Found out the reason was that I had a package.json file in my home folder that node used by default and it messed things up. Had to delete `~/package.json` file and problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you. I was in Webstorm pouring over my config and couldn't figure out why I could lint but Eslint would timeout starting the language service process. I also had a pakage.json in my home along with other garbage because I accidentally started an init for a project from my home directory. THIS HELPED A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Typescript in settings sidebar, and you reference the correct path of node interpreter in node interpreter input that you see there

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Problem was setting current node interpreter version in intellij (Settings->Languages&Frameworks->NodeJS and NPM)

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the previous two. The only difference is that @Kai Mollerud added a bit more details

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in an Angular TypeScript project. ESLint was linting .ts files obviously. However, I also had some HLS video chunks in my project which also use a .ts extension. When I deleted the HLS chunks, the problem disappeared. I tried adding the folder containing the HLS chunks to .eslintignore but no joy. I'm still refining how to deal with the issue without deleting the HLS chunks. I may be forced to change the extension of the chunk files but hoping I can find a better solution.